# Do historians have a method to synthesize evidence and conclusions from multiple fields?

Tags: theory

Modern historians when trying to understand some specific aspect of the past often have to draw on multiple types of evidence, such as historical documents, literature, [epigraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraphy), numismatics, linguistics, and  archaeology.

Each of these types of evidence have their own specialists, theories, methodology, and opinions. If we're looking at a specific topic, such as religion, the number of specialties involved can increase to include religious studies, philosophy, and even folklore studies.

How do historians synthesize all this evidence and the different specialist ways of understanding the evidence and/or society, given that these fields may come to different conflicting conclusions which are yet methodologically sound in their own field?

I'm aware of some attempts at this such as [Meta-Ethnography: Synthesizing Qualitative Studies 1988](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Meta_Ethnography.html?id=e1eAAAAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y), [Narrative Synthesis
Considerations and challenges 2016](https://journals.lww.com/ijebh/Abstract/2016/12000/Narrative_Synthesis__Considerations_and_challenges.33.aspx#:%7E:text=Narrative%20synthesis%20is%20a%20common,of%20narrative%20syntheses%20is%20limited.&text=Narrative%20synthesis%20goes%20beyond%20the,main%20features%20of%20included%20studies.).

As well as attempts at understanding the relationship between these bodies of thoughts from within others such as [Archaeology and Folklore (Theoretical Archaeology Group S.) 1999](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Archaeology-Folklore-Theoretical-Group/dp/0415201446) and [Religion, Material Culture and Archaeology 2012](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Religion_Material_Culture_and_Archaeolog.html?id=hA-KP_8V47gC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) .

But how successful or widespread these ideas have become? I don't know.

Comment: We do in general take a rather holistic approach to human history on this site. I know it has its champions in popular culture (eg: Jared Diamond), but I'm not tied in to the academic community enough to know what's going on there.